# Using a Button Tag

Tags: c#, .net, events, thread-safety

Assuming program logic changes a button tag based on something random - but using the UI thread.

Is the Button Tag value reliable to use in a click event? i.e. Will it be the same value as-at the time of the event handler as it was at the time of the click?

If not, what is the best method to pass an event specific parameter into a button click event that will be safe?

**Update**

Added an example as requested. (Remember this is just theoretical).

```
Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1;
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_tick);
timer.Start();

void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button.Tag = Random.NextInt(100).ToString();
}

void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = (string)((Button)sender).Tag;
    Console.WriteLine("Tag value as at button push: " + s);
}
```

Put another way, the question boils down to: can events be wedged into the GUI event queue that allow the state of the button to be changed between the button being pushed and the click event handling the push?

Comment: Please define button tag. And how your logic can change it? Is this regarding, a windows application?

Comment: Actually I'm using wpf, but I assume winforms answers would be similar enough for the question. In terms of how the logic changes the tag - think of a GUI based timer changing the Tag onces a millisecond. (This is theoretical).

Comment: can you give an example how you are making change in the button tag.

Comment: Edited question to add simplistic example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using winforms.

IMHO you can use `Tag` property to pass control specific parameters but you must also remember that windows forms controls are not thread safe. To make a thread-safe call, you must use `InvokeRequired`. The following link gives an example to set text for TextBox in a thread-safe way but it should not be very different for `Tag` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(VS.80).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I attempted to convey with the question was that the changing of the Tag property is done via the GUI thread - not some other thread. So multi-thread safety isn't an issue here. With or without invoking it does not change the question.

Comment: Oh sorry i misunderstood the question. Anyways IMO Tag property is as reliable as it gets. I have used Tag property extensively to give more information about the control, etc. so that the same can be used inside the event handler.